# How to print out the elements in a list that begin with a certain letter

Tags: python, list

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
for continent in continents:
    print(continent)

if continent[0] == 'A':
    print(continent)
```

This is my code that I have used. Could someone see if there is a way to print out the continents that only begin with the letter "A"?

Comment: Think about how you can combine that `if` at the bottom with the `for` loop that you have.

Comment: check for empty string, handle case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try this one

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
for continent in continents:
    if continent[0] == 'A':
        print(continent)
```

- output:

```
Asia
Africa
Antarctica
Australia
```

Answer (score 6):

Use startswith()

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
for continent in continents:
    if continent.startswith('A'):
        print(continent)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Use a simple list comprehension:

```py
[continent for continent in continents if continent.startswith('A')]
```

2. Use a very similar generator expression:

```py
(continent for continent in continents if continent.startswith('A'))
```

3. Use a simple filter expression:

```py
filter(lambda x: x.startswith('A'), continents)
```

2 and 3 is light on on memory - you can use it if you have a data-set that is *really* huge. 3 is a *functional* way of writing the same thing.

Comment: you can use regex too in lambda like this.   list(filter(lambda x: bool(re.match('a|A', x)), continents))

Comment: print(*list(filter(lambda x: bool(re.match('a|A', x)), continents)), sep="\n") chek this out.

Comment: @AkashPagar, Doesn't that match anywhere? Simple/readable solution is the best if it has performance problems.

Answer (score 3):

just indent the `if` in order for it being inside the loop. (because we want the `for` loop to go through the list and check for every element if it starts with 'A')

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
for continent in continents:
    if continent[0] == 'A':
      print(continent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like that:

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]

a_continents = [c for c in continents if c.startswith('A')]
# Or:
# a_continents = [c for c in continents if c and c[0] == 'A']

print(a_continents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code using while loop with elapsed time(Time taken by code to execute task)

```
from datetime import datetime

continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
i = 0
continent = sorted(continents)
start_time = datetime.now().time().microsecond
while i < len(continent):
    if (continent[i][0] == 'A'):
        print(continent[i])
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
end_time = datetime.now().time().microsecond
print('Time taken :', end_time - start_time, 'ms')
```

OutPut:-

```
Africa
Antarctica
Asia
Australia
Time taken : 45 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
aNamedContinents = c
    for c in continents:
        if c.startswith('A'):
            print(c)
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally more helpful if they include context; otherwise your answer may get downvoted and possibly deleted by users with the delete vote privilege.

Answer (score -1):

Use an if statement inside the for loop:

```
continents = [
    'Asia',
    'South America',
    'North America',
    'Africa',
    'Europe',
    'Antarctica',
    'Australia',
]
for continent in continents:
    if continent[0] == 'A':
        print(continent)
```